# Store jquery selector in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

In the following example the `stored jQuery selector` returns the wrong value.
There is a possibility to store the selectors and not the result?

The js code:

```
// storing the jQuery selectors
var
  $container = $( '.container' ),
  $element1  = $container.find( '.element' ),
  $element2  = $( '.element', $container ),
  $element3  = $( '.element' );

// append elements to the container
for( i=0; i<10; ++i ){
  $container.append( $(element_html) );  
}

// try the stored selectors -> returns 0
console.log( "1: " + $element1.length );
console.log( "2: " + $element2.length );
console.log( "3: " + $element3.length );
```

Why, if I use the container selectors to find the elements, it works?
It is beacuse the selector returns the `pointer` to the matched elements and not the elements?

```
// this works
console.log( "1: " + $container.find( '.element' ).length );
console.log( "2: " + $( '.element', $container )  .length );
console.log( "3: " + $( '.element' )              .length );
```

[**jsFiddle demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/SxC3S/)

Comment: jquery selectors return a query object on which you can do further operations, which is called chaining...

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of what

```
variableName = $("selector here");
```

does. It does not "store the selector." It runs the selector you give against the *current* elements in the DOM, creates a jQuery object, puts the matching elements in the jQuery object, and gives you a reference to that jQuery object. The selector is not stored (modulo jQuery internals).

So given:

```
<body>
<div class="foo">x</div>
</body>
```

Then:

```
var $divs = $("div.foo");
console.log($divs.length);        // 1
```

Gives us this:

[image: $divs jQuery object pointing at one div in the DOM]

If we then add another matching `div`:

```
$('<div class="foo"></div>').appendTo(document.body);
```

Our `$divs` still only points to the first one; adding another matching element to the DOM had no effect on the jQuery object referenced from `$divs`.

[image: $divs jQuery object pointing to one div, but there are two in the DOM]

If we re-run the query at that point:

```
$divs = $("div.foo");
```

...then we have:

[image: $divs jQuery object pointing at both divs in the DOM]

If you have a jQuery object containing a DOM element, and you add *descendant* elements to that DOM element, then using that jQuery object with (say) `.find` will see the descendants. That's because the parent DOM element is already there in the jQuery object. E.g., adding a `span` to one of the `div`s that we *already* reference from our jQuery object:

[image: $divs jQuery object pointing at both divs in the DOM, one has a span now]

If we were to use `.find` on `$divs` at that point looking for a `span`, we'd find it, because it's a descendant of one of the elements we already had a reference to.

If you want to re-run the DOM search again later to look for matching elements, you just use `$()` again; this is implicit in the above, but for clarity:

```
var $divs = $("div.foo");
console.log($divs.length);        // 1
$('<div class="foo"></div>').appendTo(document.body);
console.log($divs.length);        // Still 1
$divs = $("div.foo");
console.log($divs.length);        // Now it's 2
```

So "storing a selector," when needed, is a matter of storing the selector string somewhere, not the jQuery object.

Comment: So in answer to his question, storing the selector should be done by storing the `string` as opposed to the returned jQuery object. (Just wanted to add that, sorry if it's trivial :))

Comment: Can I see the return of a jQuery selector like an `array of pointers` to the DOM elements?

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik: Yes, exactly. I've added some pictures to the answer to make that a bit clearer. jQuery objects are "sets" (as in set theory) of elements that matched the selector as of when you created the object.

Comment: what if i have a unique elements that i'm using frequently , should i store them in variables so jquery won't search in the dom every time to find them again ?

Comment: @robert: How long is a piece of string? It totally depends.

Answer (score 6):

I think the accepted answer is excellent, but it could be interpreted to suggest that assigning JQuery objects to variables is always unsafe. Doing so is fine -- *as long as the DOM object the variable references is not altered before you access it in a way that affects later code*.

**HTML**

```
<div id="banner-message">
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <button>Change view</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  banner.addClass("alt");
  banner.hide().html("New HTML").fadeIn(2000);
})
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BobRay/7sfb0u3e/)