# Double slideshow with previous/next buttons

Tags: jquery, navigation, slider, jquery-selectors

I'm fairly new to jQuery, and JS in general. I've got a slideshow with thumbnails that I had working, but then I add in previous/next buttons and it doesn't work at all now. I just need help figuring this out. Been banging my head against the wall for the last two hours. It's a slideshow with images above the thumbnails and content beneath. I just want be able to switch both, images above and content beneath while showing active states on the thumbnails. It works until you use the next/prev buttons.

```js
 $('.filmstrip div span').on('click', function(){
  var guts_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
  $('.filmstrip div span').removeClass('current').addClass('gs');
  $(this).toggleClass('current gs');
  $('.guts, .hero-image').removeClass('active');
  $('.'+guts_id).addClass('active');
 });

 // var guts_id = $('.filmstrip div span').attr('data-tab');

 var fSlide = $('li:first', 'ul');
 var lSlide = $('li:last', 'ul');

 var fGuts = $('section:first', '.guts-wrapper');
 var lGuts = $('section:last', '.guts-wrapper');

 var fThumb = $('.thumb:first', '.filmstrip');
 var lThumb = $('.thumb:last', '.filmstrip');

 var $nextSlide = $('.hero .active').next('li').length ? $('.hero .active').next('li') : fSlide;
 var $prevSlide = $('.hero .active').prev('li').length ? $('.hero .active').prev('li') : lSlide;

 var $nextGuts = $('.guts-wrapper .active').next('section').length ? $('.guts-wrapper .active').next('section') : fGuts;
 var $prevGuts = $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section').length ? $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section') : lGuts;

 var $nextThumb = $('.filmstrip .alive').next('.thumb').length ? $('.filmstrip .alive').next('.thumb') : fThumb;
 var $prevThumb = $('.filmstrip .alive').prev('.thumb').length ? $('.filmstrip .alive').prev('.thumb') : lThumb;

 // var $nextThumb = $('.filmstrip .thumb .current').next('.thumb').length ? $('.filmstrip .thumb .current').next('.thumb') : fThumb;
 // var $prevThumb = $('.filmstrip .thumb .current').prev('.thumb').length ? $('.filmstrip .thumb .current').prev('.thumb') : lThumb;
 // var $currentThumb = $('.filmstrip .current');

 $('.next').on('click', function(){
  $('.hero .active').removeClass('active');
  $('.guts-wrapper .active').removeClass('active');
  $('.filmstrip .alive').removeClass('alive').find('.thumb > .current').removeClass('current').addClass('gs');
  $nextSlide.addClass('active');
  $nextGuts.addClass('active');
  $nextThumb.addClass('alive').find('span').addClass('current').removeClass('gs');
  $nextSlide = $('.hero .active').next('li').length ? $('.hero .active').next('li') : fSlide;
  $prevSlide = $('.hero .active').prev('li').length ? $('.hero .active').prev('li') : lSlide;
  $nextGuts = $('.guts-wrapper .active').next('section').length ? $('.guts-wrapper .active').next('section') : fGuts;
  $prevGuts = $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section').length ? $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section') : lGuts;
  $nextThumb = $('.filmstrip .alive').next('.thumb').length ? $('.filmstrip .alive').next('.thumb') : fThumb;
  $prevThumb = $('.filmstrip .alive').prev('.thumb').length ? $('.filmstrip .alive').prev('.thumb') : lThumb;

 });

 $('.previous').on('click', function(){
  $('.hero .active').removeClass('active');
  $('.guts-wrapper .active').removeClass('active');
  $('.filmstrip .alive').removeClass('alive').find('.thumb > .current').removeClass('current').addClass('gs');
  $prevSlide.addClass('active');
  $prevGuts.addClass('active');
  $prevThumb.addClass('alive').find('span').addClass('current').removeClass('gs');
  $prevSlide = $('.hero .active').prev('li').length ? $('.hero .active').prev('li') : fSlide;
  $prevSlide = $('.hero .active').prev('li').length ? $('.hero .active').prev('li') : lSlide;
  $prevGuts = $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section').length ? $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section') : fGuts;
  $prevGuts = $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section').length ? $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section') : lGuts;
  $nextThumb = $('.filmstrip .alive').next('.thumb').length ? $('.filmstrip .alive').next('.thumb') : fThumb;
  $prevThumb = $('.filmstrip .alive').prev('.thumb').length ? $('.filmstrip .alive').prev('.thumb') : lThumb;
 });
```

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
}
.hero {
  width: 800px;
  height: 275px;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.hero-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hero-image.content1 {
  background: orange;
  height: 275px;
}
.hero-image.content2 {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  height: 275px;
}
.hero-image.content3 {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 275px;
}
.guts.content1 {
  background: red;
  height: 275px;
}
.guts.content2 {
  background: blue;
  height: 275px;
}
.guts.content3 {
  background: green;
  height: 275px;
}

.hero-image.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 3;
}

.filmstrip {
  padding: 0;
  height: 10rem;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.filmstrip .button {
  *zoom: 1;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  text-align: inherit;
  width: 22.5%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  height: 10rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}
.filmstrip .button:before,
.filmstrip .button:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
.filmstrip .button:after {
  clear: both;
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow {
  *zoom: 1;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 16.25%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 10rem;
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow:before,
.filmstrip .button.arrow:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow:after {
  clear: both;
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow span {
  position: relative;
  top: initial;
  left: initial;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 10rem;
  display: block;
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i:before,
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i.left,
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i.right {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 3rem;
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i.left:before,
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i.right:before,
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i.left:after,
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i.right:after {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 2px;
  top: 50%;
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i.left {
  right: 1.5rem;
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i.left:before,
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i.left:after {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i.right {
  left: 1.5rem;
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i.right:before,
.filmstrip .button.arrow span i.right:after {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow span:hover i:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-70deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-70deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-70deg);
  transform: rotate(-70deg);
}
.filmstrip .button.arrow span:hover i:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(70deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(70deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(70deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(70deg);
  transform: rotate(70deg);
}
.filmstrip .button span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
}
.filmstrip .button span:after {
  content: '';
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s all ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s all ease;
  -o-transition: 0.25s all ease;
  -ms-transition: 0.25s all ease;
  transition: 0.25s all ease;
}
.filmstrip .button span img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.filmstrip .button span.gs img:last-child {
  display: none;
}
.filmstrip .button.next:hover span:after,
.filmstrip .button.previous:hover span:after {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
.filmstrip .button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.filmstrip .button:hover span:after {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.guts-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  *zoom: 1;
}
.guts-wrapper:before,
.guts-wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
.guts-wrapper:after {
  clear: both;
}
.guts-wrapper .guts {
  display: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.guts-wrapper .guts.active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <ul class="hero cf">
    <li class="hero-image one active content1">
     
    </li>

    <li class="hero-image two content2">
     
    </li>

    <li class="hero-image three content3">
     
    </li>
   </ul>


   <section class="filmstrip">
    <div class="button arrow previous">
     <span>&lt;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="button ">
     <span data-tab="content1"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x75" alt=""></span>
    </div>
    <div class="button ">
     <span data-tab="content2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x75" alt=""></span>
    </div>
    <div class="button ">
     <span data-tab="content3"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x75" alt=""></span>
    </div>
    <div class="button arrow next">
     <span>&gt;</span>
    </div>
   </section>
   

   <div class="guts-wrapper">
    <section class="guts content1 active">
     SLIDE #1 CONTENT GOES HERE
    </section>
    <section class="guts content2">
     SLIDE #2 CONTENT GOES HERE
    </section>
    <section class="guts content3">
     SLIDE #3 CONTENT GOES HERE
    </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

I stripped back  some of it and simplified the mess I had previously. Here's a fiddle:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b84atsrq/8/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know it's something simple, but I have to walk away at this point or else I'm going to go crazy.

**EDIT:** I was able to get it working. I adjusted the code above, but I'm not sure the best way to tie in the thumbnails to the next/prev events. You see the "current" class is no longer added to the thumbnails when you click the next/prev buttons. I know there should be a simple way to do this, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I cleaned up the JS a bit to remove all the stuff I was trying. Any thoughts?

**EDIT 2:** I figured it out. I just was thinking the wrong way. Regardless, I still believe there's a better, more succinct way to write this. I updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code.

1. The `activeSlide` variable does not suit your need because the element which has `.active` class changes by sliding to the previous or next li. What you are doing is basically finding the element with `.active` class and point it out through your code forever. In this case, it is better to use `$(".active")` so that it will search DOM to find the element with `active` class. For more reading, refer to [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053838/store-jquery-selector-in-variable)
2. You are not updating `prevSlide` and `nextSlide` inside of your click events for the buttons. When you move to the next or previous slides, you need to set the new element. You need to update both `prevSlide` and `nextSlide` in both click events.

Check out a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/VeowKe?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I see better what's happening now. I'll get back to it to see if I can get the content below to update as well when you click prev/next.That's still another part of the question that I couldn't quite figure out.

Comment: I just edited my post with updated code, but can't seem to figure out how to add the "current" class to the thumbnails with the next/prev buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in my edit above... I'm positive there's a much better way to do this. I just created a variable for the thumbs and followed the same convention for the pieces of content. @zero point, thanks for getting me on the right track.

```
    var fSlide = $('li:first', 'ul');
var lSlide = $('li:last', 'ul');

var fGuts = $('section:first', '.guts-wrapper');
var lGuts = $('section:last', '.guts-wrapper');

var fThumb = $('.thumb:first', '.filmstrip');
var lThumb = $('.thumb:last', '.filmstrip');

var $nextSlide = $('.hero .active').next('li').length ? $('.hero .active').next('li') : fSlide;
var $prevSlide = $('.hero .active').prev('li').length ? $('.hero .active').prev('li') : lSlide;

var $nextGuts = $('.guts-wrapper .active').next('section').length ? $('.guts-wrapper .active').next('section') : fGuts;
var $prevGuts = $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section').length ? $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section') : lGuts;

var $nextThumb = $('.filmstrip .alive').next('.thumb').length ? $('.filmstrip .alive').next('.thumb') : fThumb;
var $prevThumb = $('.filmstrip .alive').prev('.thumb').length ? $('.filmstrip .alive').prev('.thumb') : lThumb;

$('.next').on('click', function(){
    $('.hero .active').removeClass('active');
    $('.guts-wrapper .active').removeClass('active');
    $('.filmstrip .alive').removeClass('alive').find('.thumb > .current').removeClass('current').addClass('gs');
    $nextSlide.addClass('active');
    $nextGuts.addClass('active');
    $nextThumb.addClass('alive').find('span').addClass('current').removeClass('gs');
    $nextSlide = $('.hero .active').next('li').length ? $('.hero .active').next('li') : fSlide;
    $prevSlide = $('.hero .active').prev('li').length ? $('.hero .active').prev('li') : lSlide;
    $nextGuts = $('.guts-wrapper .active').next('section').length ? $('.guts-wrapper .active').next('section') : fGuts;
    $prevGuts = $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section').length ? $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section') : lGuts;
    $nextThumb = $('.filmstrip .alive').next('.thumb').length ? $('.filmstrip .alive').next('.thumb') : fThumb;
    $prevThumb = $('.filmstrip .alive').prev('.thumb').length ? $('.filmstrip .alive').prev('.thumb') : lThumb;

});

$('.previous').on('click', function(){
    $('.hero .active').removeClass('active');
    $('.guts-wrapper .active').removeClass('active');
    $('.filmstrip .alive').removeClass('alive').find('.thumb > .current').removeClass('current').addClass('gs');
    $prevSlide.addClass('active');
    $prevGuts.addClass('active');
    $prevThumb.addClass('alive').find('span').addClass('current').removeClass('gs');
    $prevSlide = $('.hero .active').prev('li').length ? $('.hero .active').prev('li') : fSlide;
    $prevSlide = $('.hero .active').prev('li').length ? $('.hero .active').prev('li') : lSlide;
    $prevGuts = $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section').length ? $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section') : fGuts;
    $prevGuts = $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section').length ? $('.guts-wrapper .active').prev('section') : lGuts;
    $nextThumb = $('.filmstrip .alive').next('.thumb').length ? $('.filmstrip .alive').next('.thumb') : fThumb;
    $prevThumb = $('.filmstrip .alive').prev('.thumb').length ? $('.filmstrip .alive').prev('.thumb') : lThumb;
});
```