# Assigning a jquery object to a variable doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone explain why one of these versions of code works and the other fails?

This doesn't work:

```
var classForSelectedElement = "hightlight";
var prevSelect = $(".form-element");
var $selectedElement = $("div").on("click", ".form-element",function(e){
    prevSelect.removeClass(classForSelectedElement);
    $(this).addClass(classForSelectedElement);
});
```

Whereas this works:

```
var classForSelectedElement = "hightlight";
var $selectedElement = $("div").on("click", ".form-element",function(e){
    $(".form-element").removeClass(classForSelectedElement);
    $(this).addClass(classForSelectedElement);
});
```

Why?

Comment: Why are you using event delegation? If you don't know what that is, you definitely need to learn about it (since you are using it). If you know what it is you basically already have your answer.

Comment: @bibangamba [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24053931/4790490) may answer your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that the `.form-element` elements are appended to the DOM dynamically after load (due to your usage of a delegated event handler) then the first example doesn't work as you are attempting to retrieve the `.form-element` on load of the page before they exist.

Comment: you're totally right(appended DOM dynamically). hadn't realized what was happening. thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.